# RForce in R tool SSO login Sales Force

Tags: r, salesforce

Recently came across RForce that can be used to connect to Sales Force. The question is instead of providing login and password for connection, is there a way to pick up Windows login for connection?

Comment: What are you talking about? Please improve your question.

Comment: I think you may mean RForcecom and that package expects (with no other option) `username` & `password` to be specified in the login function. There is also no way for R to read your Windows creds to pass them in. To use any of the various [SSO options](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/implementing-single-sign-on-for-clients) for Salesforce you'd have to figure out which one is implemented in your org and tweak the package (& RCurl setup) accordingly.